# Java can't execute cmd (powershell) command

Tags: java, powershell

I want to obtain some information from LDAP in my Java program. The problem is that i can't create a bind to LDAP via Java without passing user password while user is already logged in to system. I don't really want to use some external modules. So i decided to execute request from powershell and get the output.

I have the following code to execute powershell command:

```
private String powershell(String cmd) throws IOException {
    String temp; StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell \"" + cmd + "\"");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "Cp866"));
    while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        if (!temp.equals(""))
            result.append(temp + "\n");
    return result.toString()
}
```

I want to use something like this:

```
String result = powershell("Get-ADUser ($env:UserName) -Properties cn, mail | fl cn, mail");
System.out.println(result);
```

Important thing. Powershell module wasn't installed with RSAT-package, it was copy-pasted in: **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveDirectory** with dependencies *(2 dll files)*. I don't really want to install whole RSAT-package on users PC. May be it's the root of the problem.

Problem is that in real cmd this command works fine, but when I'm calling it from java it returns nothing ("")!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in JRE version.
Everything works fine since **JRE 9**.